# React native is not updating render UI if component is called from Android ReactActivity

Tags: android, react-native, react-component

Once we reload UI component in Android ReactNative by **getMainComponentName()**. React doesn't update the component even if there is a **change in props**.

I am sending different props each time by **ReactActivityDelegate** and the main component i.e getMainComponentName() is same. But react doesn't update component UI. It just loads(**render**) from the previous state as it is(memory I guess).

I know react should automatically re-render the DOM if there is a change in props or state, but it's not happening.

Even I am forcefully returning true from shouldComponentUpdate which has default value true.

```
 shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return true;
 }
```

Please let me know how to update render DOM each time if there is a change in props.

I don't know how to use **forceupdate()** method properly. React says it's not best practice to use forceUpdate().

I have to load **react component** from Android **ReactNative Activity**. I have verified the props **value chang**e is passing to **component's constructor** properly. But the **render** function is not being called again if the component is loaded earlier. If I do **reload** in the **emulator** the new changes are reflecting fine.

Please help me how to solve this. I am a newbie in react-native. Please excuse me if my understanding is wrong about react component.

**Update :**
Render is being called but the Native ReactMethod is not being called again if there is some change in return from @ReactMenthod.